# Download file from python into angularjs

Tags: python, angularjs, web-services, flask

I have this code which I want that user and client can download the file.

This is my service:

```
 DownLoad: function (data) {
        return $http({
          url: urlBase + 'export_file/',
          headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
          data: data,
          method: 'POST'
        });
      }
    };
```

the code above will serve as my connector for both python and angularjs

And this is my python code which I want the result to pass to my angularjs:

```
@api.route("/export_file/", methods=["POST"])
 def export_file():
  if request.method == 'POST':

    home = expanduser("~")
    home2 = os.path.join(home,"try.txt")
    ap = csv.writer(file(home2,'wb'))
    ap.writerows(["HELLOW WORLD"])
    db.session.commit()

    return jsonify({'success': True})
```

And this is my angularjs which serve as the receiver of data:

```
$scope.DLFILE = function() {
                        downloading.DownLoad()
                        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {console.log(data);
                        if (data.success) {
                            $scope.ExportDate={}
                            var blob = new Blob([data], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"}); #I add this one which came from other source, and I hope this may help to save my data.
                            saveAs(blob, "hello world.txt");
                            console.log('success!');

                        }
                        })
                        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                            console.log('error in downloading!');

                        });

                // }
            };
```

Right now when I run this, the data inside my python always save into the home directory of the server user. I want also the user in the client to download it but can save into their desired download folder. Can someone help me? I'm still confused on how to pass the data. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I wont comment on the angularjs portion. Your problem lies with how flask is handling your request.

Given a flask structure like the one below.

```
├── flasksandbox.py
├── static
│   └── downloadThis.txt
└── templates
    └── empty.html
```

And you want to allow user to download the file called downloadThis.txt

Your flask route will be :

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, send_file

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def get_file():
    return send_file('static/downloadThis.txt',as_attachment=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

If you need to stream a file instead (for instance if you file is a really huge or you want to generate it on the fly) check out http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/streaming/ , you can do the following :

```
@app.route('/stream')
def get_file_stream():
    def generate():
        for letters in "this is suppose to be a big csv file iterator or something":
            yield letters + '\n'


    return Response(generate(),
                    mimetype="text/plain",
                    headers={"Content-Disposition":
                               "attachment;filename=test.txt"})
```

At last, the headers `{ "Content-Disposition" :"attachment"filename=text.txt"}` will tell the browser handling the response to download the file as an attachment instead of displaying on the browser and the filename=text.txt will be default filename

In `send_file()`, by providing the argument `as_attachment=True`, this header infomation is automatically added to your response by flask